# yii2 dropDownTable does it exist?

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, html-table

I need often to show more attributes in a dropDownList and it's alright until the lenght of concatenated attributes is the same but as soon it's not the case, it gets confusing. Is there a workaround, or a dropDownTable for exampe where you could choose which attributes you want to show? Something like that:

```
$form->field($model, 'zwzs_id')
    ->dropDownTable(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Zwzs::find()->all()‌​,
    'id', ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', ...]),
    ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select')),
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you please add your code? It helps so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean below code:

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(['1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'],['prompt'=>'Select Option']);
?>
```

Comment: no, I'm thinking rather of something like that: `$form->field($model, 'zwzs_id')->dropDownTable(
                        \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Zwzs::find()->all(), 'id', ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', ...]), [
                    'prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select')),` and then the list would be rendered as a small table, where you can show more attributes nicely tabulated.